# I'm new, can't update Spyder to 4.0.1

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I just installed Anaconda for an online class and when I opened Spyder it said that a new version of Spyder was available so I thought I'd update through the Anaconda prompt. However when I type in

```
conda update spyder
```

it returns with

```
 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1074, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_update.py", line 20, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'update')
  File "C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 116, in install
    if context.use_only_tar_bz2:
  File "C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 666, in use_only_tar_bz2
    import conda_package_handling.api
  File "C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 7, in <module>
    import tqdm as _tqdm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'
```

`$ C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\Scripts\conda-script.py update spyder`

```
environment variables:
             CIO_TEST=<not set>
    CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
            CONDA_EXE=C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
           CONDA_EXES="C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
                      "
         CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
     CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\python.exe
           CONDA_ROOT=C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol
          CONDA_SHLVL=1
             HOMEPATH=\Users\sydne
                 PATH=C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol;C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Docume
                      nts\PyMol\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMo
                      l\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\Library\bin;
                      C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\Scripts;C:\Users\sydne\OneDriv
                      e\Documents\PyMol\bin;C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol;C:\Users
                      \sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\sydne\O
                      neDrive\Documents\PyMol\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Docume
                      nts\PyMol\Library\bin;C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\Scripts;
                      C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\bin;C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Do
                      cuments\PyMol\condabin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\Syste
                      m32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System3
                      2\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
                      Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Compo
                      nents\DAL;C:\Users\sydne\Anaconda3;C:\Users\sydne\Anaconda3\Library\mi
                      ngw-w64\bin;C:\Users\sydne\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\sydne\An
                      aconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\sydne\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\sydne\Ap
                      pData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
         PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Windows
                      PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
   REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
        SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

 active environment : base
active env location : C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol
        shell level : 1
   user config file : C:\Users\sydne\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\.condarc
                      C:\Users\sydne\.condarc
      conda version : 4.7.12
conda-build version : not installed
     python version : 3.7.4.final.0
   virtual packages :
   base environment : C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol  (writable)
       channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/conda_forge/win-64
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/conda_forge/noarch
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/schrodinger/win-64
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/schrodinger/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
      package cache : C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\pkgs
                      C:\Users\sydne\.conda\pkgs
                      C:\Users\sydne\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
   envs directories : C:\Users\sydne\OneDrive\Documents\PyMol\envs
                      C:\Users\sydne\.conda\envs
                      C:\Users\sydne\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
           platform : win-64
         user-agent : conda/4.7.12 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
      administrator : False
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
```

It's a little bit overwhelming to look at for a first timer, so if anyone could give any advice as to whether I'm missing any packages or anything that would be helpful.

I don't know if this is relevant, but when I was installing it I was asked to both “Add Anaconda to my PATH environment variable”, and “Register Anaconda as my default Python 3.5.” for the purposes of the class. One of the options came up as 'not recommended'in the Setup Wizard, but it might have nothing to do with the problem at all.

Comment: You Anaconda installation is broken, so you need to uninstall it and reinstall it again.

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba Tried that and typed 'conda update spyder' into the Anaconda prompt and then returned with this:

'Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
  channel name: conda_forge
  channel url: https://conda.anaconda.org/conda_forge
  error code: 404

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.'